# Joint table with optional relation

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have three models:

- Company;
- Investor;
- Broker.

in real world each investor can invest in many companies, but in some he/she can invest with broker assistance.
I made it through joint table.

```
def change
  create_join_table :companies, :investors do |t|
    t.references :broker, index: true, optional: true
  end
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :investors
end

class Investor < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
end

class Broker < < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :companies
end
```

How should I configure my models/migrations to have next information:

```
Company.first.investors.first.broker
```

broker is not belongs to investor, in each company/investor pair can be different broker.

Answer (score 1):

Use [has_many through associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)  and add the broker on the join model. After adding the proper migrations your models will look like this:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :company_investors
  has_many :investors, through: :company_investors
end

class Investor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :company_investors
  has_many :companies, through: :company_investors
end

class Broker < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :company_investors
  has_many :companies, through: :company_investors
end

class CompanyInvestor < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :broker
  belongs_to :investor
  belongs_to :company
end
```

With this models, you can add `Investor` to `Company` associations with or without `Broker`, and also discriminate them. I also recommend naming the join model (which in my code I named `CompanyInvestor`) a more significant name, like `Investment`

Comment: that doesn't work as I need I can't get broker directly from company.investor pair

Company.first.investors.first.broker

Comment: You can select `Broker` from `Investment`, `Investor` or `Company` by `Investment.first.broker`, `Company.first.investments.first.broker`, or `Investor.first.investments.broker`. You can also fetch an `Investment` from a `Company` and `Investor` pair, then selecting this `Investment`'s `Broker`. You won't be able to fetch `Broker` from `Investor` and satisfy this condition "broker is not belongs to investor". To select a `Broker` from Company/Investment do `Investment.where(company: any_company, investor: any_investor).broker`

Comment: errata: `Investment.where(company: any_company, investor: any_investor).first.broker`